# How to interpolate a byte slice?

Tags: go

I'm attempting to build a JSON payload for a POST request:

```
var payload = []byte(`{"foo":"bar", "hello":"world"}`)
```

However, I would like the values to be interpolated from an existing string. I've tried to use `%s`, but this is obviously not syntactically correct:

```
var payload = []byte(`{"foo":%s, "hello":%s}`, val1, val2)
```

Feels like I'm going about this the entirely wrong way. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `go version go1.3.3 darwin/amd64`

Comment: I really wish I could delete this question :flushed:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use `%s`, you need a formatting function.

```
var payload = []byte(fmt.Sprintf(`{"foo":%q, "hello":%q}`, val1, val2))
```

(`%q` is like `%s` but adds quotes for you)